# Set all my foreach loop data into one variable like $results

Tags: php, class, foreach

I have a simple foreach like the following:

```
$range = range(1, 10);
foreach ($range as $times) {
   echo 'example' . $times . '<br>';
}
```

what would output the result below-

```
example1
example2
example3
example4
example5
example6
example7
example8
example9
example10
```

instead of having the `echo 'example' . $times . '<br>';`
i would like to echo one variable and have the same result, any answers welcome.

Comment: Concat it into a string instead of `echo`ing it?  Append it to an array then `echo implode("\n", $results)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean build a string?

```
$results = '';
foreach(range(1, 10) as $i) {
   $results .= "example${i}\n";
}
```

Comment: will help if user want to echo text just after `exampleN` ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to make an array, you can do something like:

```
$results = '';
$range = range(1, 10);
foreach ($range as $times) {
    $results .= "example".$times."<br />";
}
echo $results;
```